Android, expose extern C functions to dylib
I have a Rust library that I have compiled for Android as a cdylib (.so). This library needs to call some exposed functionality dependent on the platform. Let's call this function foo. On iOS I have just created the header and exposed the functions like this:
// iOSHelper.h
OBJC_EXTERN void foo();

// iOSHelper.mm
extern "C" {

void foo() {
// Do stuff in objc
}

}

In my Rust library I just declare the functions and then can call them:
use std::ffi::{c_char, CString};

extern "C" {
    fn foo();
}

I want to do the same in Android. I have followed the steps to create a normal Android module with C++ code. I have modified my CMakeLists.txt file so that it compiles the c++ code in a static manner:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project("foo")

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    # List C/C++ source files with relative paths to this CMakeLists.txt.
    foo.cpp)

target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set_target_properties(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_OPTIONS "-std=c++17"
)
# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link libraries from various origins, such as libraries defined in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or Android system libraries.
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    # List libraries link to the target library
    android
    log)

# Set the library output directory
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI})

I have created a header in cpp/include/foo.h:

extern "C" {
void foo();
}

And tried to implement the functionality in cpp/foo.cpp:

#include "include/foo.h"

void foo() {}

However, when my app starts and I load the dylib:
class Foo {

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("foo") // Load the rust library
        }
    }
}

I get the following error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "foo" referenced by "/data/app/~~uT0giQg3B3OkjA789ded4w==/com.example-1q83pnCnnYTkRCZ2jCkisQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so"...

Is there anyway I can expose the C functions/headers to a dynamically loaded.so?
